# How to highlight ctags generated by Universal Ctags in Vim?

Tags: vim, ctags, vim-syntax-highlighting, neovim

The only plugin I found that highlights `ctags` is [TagHighlight](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2646) that uses [Exuberant Ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/).
Exuberant Ctags seems abandoned and I think it is generally concluded that Universal-Ctags is a better choice.
Is it possible to use [Universal Ctags](https://ctags.io/) to highlight user-defined types in Vim (for example objects)?
There should be a manual way to do this, but I couldn't found anything.

*I use Neovim.*

Answer (score 2):

Just because TagHighlight hasn't published new versions in recent years doesn't mean that the plugin does work any longer. The last activity on Bitbucket was one year ago; it may very well just be a mature plugin. Vim's API is very stable, and backwards compatibility is very important to Bram, so you can still use a plugin even if there's no active maintainer any longer.

The [easytags plugin](https://github.com/xolox/vim-easytags#the-highlighttags-command) also hasn't seen updates in quite some time, but I still use it, and it offers the requested functionality via a `:HighlightTags` command, although its main purpose is automated updating of tags.

Comment: I didn't say anything negative about TagHighlight other than the fact that it needs Exuberant Ctags and doesn't work (as far as I can tell) with Universal Ctags. The "outdated" part was meant for Exuberant Ctags.

Comment: I think my question is fair, since I am trying to find a solution that works with Universal Ctags. If there is non, I will consider using Exuberant Ctags.

Comment: Oh, I misattributed the abandoned part to the plugin itself. Easytags plugin uses Exuberant ctags by default (or basically anything named `ctags` found in the PATH), but can be configured to use a different tool. As long as the invocation and output is compatible, I think this shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: @rect0x51 Universal Ctags should be almost drop-in replacement for Exuberant Ctags, so it should work OOtB.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it to work (there was a slight caveat).

[vim-easytags](https://github.com/xolox/vim-easytags) has a version checking functionality which basically matching the output of `ctags --version` command with some regex in order to extract a version number. For some reason, when using Universal Ctags, that output is:

```
Universal Ctags 0.0.0(45968eff), Copyright (C) 2015 Universal Ctags Team
Universal Ctags is derived from Exuberant Ctags.
Exuberant Ctags 5.8, Copyright (C) 1996-2009 Darren Hiebert
...
```

The regex mistakes the version for 0.0.0.
There are several solution, among which:

1. Disable the version check entirely
2. Make the regex more robust
3. Rewrite the version check to account for Universal Ctags too

I am happy with option 1.